# Change route from store in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mobx

I have a React component that takes in username and password and sends it for authentication. If authentication is successful, the page should move to a different route which renders another component.

Now the problem is, I am not sure how I can change route from my store? i.e. without using the `<Link>` component of React Router? I know that we can use `this.props.history.push(/url)` to change route programatically, but it can only be used inside a React Component using `<Route>`, not from the store.

I am using React16 with MobX for state management, and ReactRouter V4 for routing.

Store:

```
class Store {
    handleSubmit = (username, password) => {
        const result = validateUser(username, password);
        // if result === true, change route to '/search' to render Search component
    }
}
```

Login Component:

```
const Login = observer(({ store }) => {
    return (
        <div>
           <form onSubmit={store.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" onChange={e => store.updateUsername(e)} value={store.username} />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" onChange={e => store.updatePassword(e)} value={store.password} />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={store.disableSearch} />
            </form>}
        </div>
    )
})
```

Main App Component:

```
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
@observer
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/"
                        component={() => <Login store={store} />}
                    />

                    <Route path="/search"
                        component={() => <Search store={store} />}
                    />
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mobx but I can use a custom history in my action creators with Redux for example. You are using Router instead of BrowserRouter and passing a custom history. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the `history` in a separate module, and import that both in your main app Component and Store:

```
// history.js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

export default history;

// Store.js
import history from './history';

class Store {
    handleSubmit = (username, password) => {
        const result = validateUser(username, password);

        if (result) {
            history.push('/search');
        }
    }
}

// App.js
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import history from './history';

@observer
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/"
                        component={() => <Login store={store} />}
                    />

                    <Route path="/search"
                        component={() => <Search store={store} />}
                    />
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @maverick Great! Glad it was useful.

Comment: I am having a small issue with above approach. I added this code to constructor of above class: `constructor() {
        history.push('/');
    }`. When I run my unit tests in Jest, I get an error saying 'SecurityError: Could not parse url argument "/" to pushState against base URL "about:blank".' I searched for this issue but could not find anything. I thought maybe it's because test is running in Node and not browser, so I changed the code to `constructor() {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            history.push('/');
        }
    }`, but it did not work.

Comment: Any clue as to why this is happening? My tests are failing due to this, and I don't want to mock the entire store as it would be a bit tedious.

Comment: Very easy and cool examples. But, is there any pitfalls by doing it this way?

Comment: @Englund0110 It will work fine if you are building an app that is run in the browser, but some extra logic will be needed if you are creating a server rendered app.