# Why do we need to render a component to issue a redirect in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In react-router v4 we now need to use a component to redirect the user to somewhere else.

While it makes sense when building the routes component (so a route can issue a redirection), it's very odd when, say, you have an error and must redirect somewhere, or redirect after a user action (that's not a simple link click).

Besides linking similar routes, redirections are also a reactive action, so why there's no API method for redirects, only a component?

Comment: You can use `this.props.history.replace` or `this.props.history.push` if you want to redirect programmatically, [or create the `history` object yourself and use it programmatically wherever you like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967404/change-route-from-store-in-react-application/50967604#50967604).

Comment: Alright, this seems like a doc issue by the time I had this problem. Sorry for the dup ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some cases where `<Redirect />` is quite nice to use.

But, this is not a must.

There are many cases I created my "programmatically redirection" and you can use "history" that you get in props.

`this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

if you don't have access to "history" in your props, as your component is not rendered inside the Route.

You can use the helper `withRouter`:

```
import {
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and just wrap your component with it, and you will have the history accessable as a prop.

```
const yourComponent = props => {
    // this.props.history is here

    return <div> dont care </div>;
}
```